# Maximum Xml File Size Handled by SAX Parser in iOS

Tags: iphone, xml, xml-parsing, filesize, max

I need to handle more than 70mb of xml file in iPad. What is the maximum file size is possible to handle in iPhone or iPad.

How to handle these kind of big files in iPhone? Is there any open source parser for parse the xml files in iPhone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAX is a stream/event based framework where you code handlers to process an event whenever a tag, comment, text, etc is encountered in the input stream.  If you are not building a tree of some kind but only extracting what you need, then the limit depends on what you keep.  There is no other limit other than CPU time to process and ignore data you don't need.

Comment: Thanks for your comment :) But i need one more clarification so if we take the data from this 70 mb file how to store the data for processing purpose. In the sense it will not affect the nsdicitionary also right?

Comment: @Vignesh what you do after you run the 70mb of data through SAX is up to you.  If you need help solving that problem, post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

One of the great solution i find in net after surfing long time is [AQXMLParser](http://quatermain.tumblr.com/post/93651539/aqxmlparser-big-memory-win).

It is the best solution in terms of memory and use.

Answer (score 0):

Another stream solution based on [libxml xmlreader](http://www.xmlsoft.org/xmlreader.html) can be found here [IGXMLReader](https://github.com/siuying/IGXMLReader)

> The IGXMLReader allows you to effectively pull parse an XML document.
>   Once instantiated, call #nextObject to iterate over each node. Note
>   that you may only iterate over the document once!